# How can I connect to copper pipe which is slightly oversized?

Tags: copper-pipe

On my 40+ year old house, I have a burst copper pipe.  It is just very slightly over 1/2". It won't fit any copper fittings I've found, and won't even fit into a pushfit like a Sharkbite fitting.  But it is extremely close.  I thought it might be metric, but the ID is 13.6mm.  Any thoughts on where I can get fittings or pipe to fit it?  It runs in the rafters above the garage, so is not insulated and must survive the winters down to -10C.

Comment: Could it have been standard 1/2" pipe, swaged wider by repeated freeze/thaw? Now wonder it burst!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  No, the entire pipe is that diameter.  It's not because of freezing.   It's just that darned size.

Comment: @crip659  I drain the pipe in the fall, but it seems there is a low point in the run so a bit of water collects there.  I'm going to fix that for the future, but I still need to repair the existing burst.

Comment: The fittings it's in now wouldn't happen to be threaded, would they? Threaded .vs. copper tube size is a very common way to get "odd sized" pipes, and some brass is very easily confused for copper, particularly with age.

Comment: please add a picture of the pipe ... it may be a part of the outside shutoff valve

Comment: 17/32 is not a size I've encountered before.  metric sizes are the same as inch sizes, just named differently.

Comment: That sounds like 15mm (OD) pipe as used here in the UK.  Where are you?

Comment: Copper may be pipe or tubing ; they are different sizes. Pipe is very specific NPS sizes . tubing may be any size. There are compression fittings for both. . Of coarse pipe fittings only fit pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace it and then insulate the cavity the pipe is in. Also add some electrical heating tape to keep it from freezing. Youir local big box store would have the tape. Reason for replacement, I think with the repeated cold weather as indicated by other the pipe expanded and the wall is thinner making it weaker and more prone to failure. If the garage is not part of the house seriously consider draining that line in the fall.

Answer (score 1):

How to join to this pipe.

anneal the cut ends (get them red hot with a propane (or MAPP, oxy, etc) torch)

rent or buy a pipe expander and stretch a socket (US:hub) into each end

then solder in new 1/2" copper between the sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Copper is available as pipe and tubing. They are different sizes. Pipe only comes in NPS sizes. Tubing maybe in any size. There are compression fittings for both. Pipe fittings will only fit pipe sizes. Copper sold in coils ( soft) is normally tubing. Copper sold in straight lengths ( hard) is normally pipe.